# $match and $cond query doesn't give the same result in MongoDB aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Considering this two different MongoDB queries:

### startDate query in $match

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{
    "$match": {
      "code": "2",
      "startDate": {
        "$lt": ISODate("2017-01-31T23:59:59.999Z")
      },
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "code": "$code"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "code" : "2"
    },
    "count" : 4844.0
}
```

### startDate query in $cond

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{
    "$match": {
      "code": "2"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "code": "$code",
      "count": {
        "$cond": [{
          "$lt": ["$startDate", ISODate('2017-01-31T23:59:59.999Z')]
        }, 1, 0]
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "code": "$code"
    },
    "count": {
      "$sum": "$count"
    }
  }
}])
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "code" : "2"
    },
    "count" : 4935.0
}
```

I don't understand why the second query give me more documents. It seems to me that this queries must give me a identical result... Am I using the "$cond" in a wrong way? What may causes this difference?

Comment: Your claimed second result is not even possible. `$project` only emits the fields you explicitly specify. You did not include `"code"` but you claim to reference it in a later aggregation stage. This is not possible, since the field is no longer there and the only returned value would in fact be `null`

Comment: I will update the question, because it's just an error of copy/paste. My query is  more complicated than the example, but i simplify it for the question

Comment: It's still intrinsically the same thing though and should be the same result. If it's not the same then the data has likely changed. If you think it's a reproducible error then you need to provide a small dataset from which you can reproduce. My bet though would be that there are documents where `"startDate"` is not even present, and this would account for the difference, since `null` would be "logically less than" but would not even be selected by the `$match` query conditions due to BSON type. Check your data.

Comment: In brief, add `"startDate": { "$exists": true }` to the `$match`, and then the results should be the same.

Comment: @NeilLunn Indeed, I've 91 documents with a 'null' startDate, so it explains the difference! I must check for non null value in the $cond operations, which is done by default in a $match, right?

Comment: Either do the `$match` as suggested or add `$ifNull` and "default" a value which you likely want to prove as `false` in your `$cond` logic. It's also a lot better to simply put the `$cond` into the `$group` inside the `$sum`. Doing otherwise is essentially another pass through the data. Which takes time and resources, in an unnecessary way.

Comment: `"startDate": {"$ne": null }` in $match works fine ($exists will only check if the field is present) thanks @NeilLunn